# error query input type date php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

tengo una muy sencilla pregunta que me esta causando un problema en un formulario. (si v = 08-02-2023,es decir la fecha de colombia,cali igual a la funcion date,la cual me trae la fecha actual real porque sucede esto?,hay tal cual como esta copiado el codigo deberia decirme YES,pero me imprime NO,lo cual no tiene sentido basandonos en la condicional y los datos,pero si pongo en la variable $v = "09-02-2023" si sale YES,necesito que lo anterior si se cumpla porque es realmente verdadero,pero me imprime lo incorrecto,les agradezco)

```
<?php
$v = "08-02-2023";
    if(($v) < (date("d-m-y"))){
        echo $error_message = 'no';
    }elseif(($v) >= (date("d-m-y"))){
        echo $error_message = 'yes';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Revisa el valor de `date_default_timezone_get()`.

Answer (score 1):

Pero no solo lo que Juan Carlos te dice, sino también en la forma de los mensajes de salida, porque si cambias fecha buscada a **08-02-2023** te dirá que la fecha buscada **NO** es menor que la fecha actual, cuando la verdad es que si lo es. El uso de los **IF** se debe pensar en base también a lo que queremos obtener como resultado.

```
$fecha_actual = strtotime(date("d-m-Y", time()));
$fecha_actual_format = date('d-m-Y', time());
$fecha_buscada  = "08-02-2023";
$v= strtotime($fecha_buscada );

if($v < $fecha_actual){
    echo "$fecha_buscada <b>ES MENOR</b> que la fecha actual $fecha_actual_format";
} else {
    echo "$fecha_buscada <b>ES MAYOR O IGUAL</b> que la fecha actual $fecha_actual_format";
}
```

Por ultimo no olvides lo que te dice Sal en el comentario de tu pregunta. siempre verifica la **timezone** que tienes con

```
date_default_timezone_get()
```

Y si quieres cambiarla, lo haces con

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que la función date() te devuelve no una fecha, sino una cadena  de texto que se **lee** como una fecha. En realidad no estas comparando fechas, sino dos cadenas de texto (es el equivalente de comparar "a" < "b"). La forma correcta de comparar fechas es convertir esas cadenas a marcas de tiempo:

```
$fecha_actual = strtotime(date("d-m-Y", time()));
$fecha_buscada  = "09-02-2023";
$v= strtotime($fecha_buscada );

if($v < $fecha_actual){
    echo "$fecha_buscada es menor que la fecha actual: NO";        
} else {
    echo "$fecha_buscada es mayor o igual que la fecha actual: SI";
}
```